# Swift 3 Extension of generic Obj-c cannot access class' generic parameters

Tags: ios, swift

```
extension PHFetchResult: Sequence {
    public  func makeIterator() -> NSFastEnumerationIterator {
    return NSFastEnumerationIterator(self)
    }
}
```

Did apple fix this bug? Or is there a 'working' workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Did apple fix this bug

No. Basically you just can't use `for...in` with a PHFetchResult any more. Fortunately there are other ways to cycle through your PHFetchResult; they are just ugly, that's all. Example from my code:

```
let result = PHCollectionList.fetchCollectionLists(with:
            .momentList, subtype: .momentListYear, options: opts)
for ix in 0..<result.count {
    let list = result[ix]
    // ...
}
```

(For a while you couldn't subscript a PHFetchResult either, but now at least you can do that.)

Comment: Thank you Matt, I guess we have to work with what we have.